# What values does the function $Z(y)$ have at various interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

When $y\leq0$; $H(y)=0$

When $y>0$;  $H(y)=e^{-\dfrac1y}$

What values does the function $Z(y)$ have at various interval? Where $Z(y)=H(1-y)(1+y)$

Please show this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** OP has indicated that the parentheses are correct, which means that the expression should be read as $(1+y)H(1-y)$. In that case, $Z(y)=0$ when $y\ge 1$, and $Z(y)=(1+y)e^{-1/(1-y)}$ when $y\lt 1$. There is no further useful simplification.

**Previous answer:**

I have a strong feeling there is a missing pair of parentheses, and $Z(y)$ should be defined by $Z(y)=
H((1-y)(1+y))$. So we write a solution based on that assumption.

Note that $(1-y)(1+y)\le 0$ when $y \ge 1$, and also when $y\le -1$. In the interval $-1\lt y\lt 1$, $(1-y)(1+y)$ is positive.

Since $H(w)=0$ when $w\le 0$, it follows that $H((1-y)(1+y))=0$ when $|y|\ge 0$, that is, in the intervals $(-\infty,-1]$ and $[1,\infty)$.

For $-1\lt y\lt 1$, $H((1-y)(1+y))=e^{-1/(1-y^2)}$.

Comment: No No parentheses are correct. Your assumption is false!

Comment: please can you solve according to my question

Comment: @Nrsy: You are welcome. The reason I interpreted the question as dealing with $H((1-y)(1+y))$ is that this function is "interesting." It, and close relatives, can be used to produce infinitely differentiable functions with unexpected properties.